# Acer Aspire 5755G warming

Tags: overheating, fan

Today i'd installed the Ubuntu 13.04, but my laptop

(http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/laptops/1286536/acer-aspire-5755g/specifications) is too warm!

What can i do?

Comment: Install bumblebee from here - http://www.bumblebee-project.org/ that will help to some extent

Answer (score 0):

That particular Acer netbook is running dual graphics which are both enabled at boot causing your laptop to heat up considerably and the battery to drain quicker...  You could install Bunblebee which gives you the option of enabling either the Intel or Nvidia graphics on it's own saving you power...

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: thanks, but i have now a probleme: the display so slow and choppy.